# "Trigger --- is invalid and failed re-validation"

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, database-trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER Supervisors
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON Employee
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN(new.EmpRank = 0 OR new.EmpRank = 1)
DECLARE
    supervisorRank INT;
BEGIN
    SELECT EmpRank INTO supervisorRank
    FROM Employee
    WHERE new.SupervisorID = Employee.Id;

    IF((new.SupervisorID IS NULL) OR (supervisorRank - new.EmpRank != 1)) THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20004, 'Cannot insert/update record into table Employee. Invalid supervisor.');
    END IF;
END;
```

Above is the trigger everytime I run queries, it results in me getting an error that says the trigger is invalid and failed re-validation

Comment: I'm confused as to where 'new' comes from, and I think it might cause your error. Is it supposed to be an alias?

Comment: Maybe you'll get more help if you tag Oracle.

Comment: Replace `new` with `:new`; check if `:new.SpervisiorID IS NULL` before the query; handle "no rows found" exception if necessary. If you run from sqlplus, type `show errors` to get more detail on the error after compiling the trigger.

Comment: Do you have a field named `old` or `new` ? What is the result of `show errors trigger Supervisors` ?

Answer (score 1):

When the given trigger is created it reports a compile error:

```
Trigger SUPERVISORS compiled
Errors: check compiler log
```

The compile error comes from a few missing colons(":") that should be preceding the references to "new" and "old" *within* the trigger body.

**NOTE**: colon prefixes are not required within the "WHEN" clause of the trigger here:

```
WHEN(new.EmpRank = 0 OR new.EmpRank = 1)
```

Additionally, it is always a good idea to fail early with more granular exceptions for easier debugging so I've added 2 more exceptions to handle the NULL scenario and the NO_DATA_FOUND scenario separately from the "bad rank" exception.

Here is the updated code including a test table definition and sample insert statements:

```
drop table employee
/

create table employee ( 
  id number,
  EmpRank number,
  SupervisorID number,
  primary key(id))
/

CREATE or replace TRIGGER Supervisors
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON Employee
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN(new.EmpRank = 0 OR new.EmpRank = 1)
DECLARE
    supervisorRank INT;
BEGIN
  if (:new.SupervisorID is null) then
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20006, 'Cannot insert/update record into table Employee. Required supervisor ID is missing.');
  end if;

  begin
    SELECT EmpRank INTO supervisorRank
    FROM Employee
    WHERE :new.SupervisorID = Employee.Id;
  exception when no_data_found then
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20005, 'Cannot insert/update record into table Employee. Supervisor ID not found.');
  end;

  IF (supervisorRank - :new.EmpRank != 1) THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20004, 'Cannot insert/update record into table Employee. Employee rank is not valid for given supervisor.');
  END IF;
END;
/

insert into employee values ( 6, 1, null );
insert into employee values ( 5, 1, 6 );
insert into employee values ( 4, 2, null );
insert into employee values ( 3, 1, 4 );
insert into employee values ( 2, 0, 3 );
insert into employee values ( 1, 0, 3 );
insert into employee values ( 0, 0, 4 );

exit
/
```

Below is the output from the above script showing the various exception messages. Note that I am using the new SQLcl (sql.exe) as opposed to SQL*Plus but the results should be the same.

```
SQLcl: Release 4.2.0.15.295.1605 RC on Tue Dec 08 17:07:23 2015

Copyright (c) 1982, 2015, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options


Table EMPLOYEE dropped.


Table EMPLOYEE created.


Trigger SUPERVISORS compiled


Error starting at line : 36 in command -
insert into employee values ( 6, 1, null )
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-20006: Cannot insert/update record into table Employee. Required supervisor ID is missing.
ORA-06512: at "APPS.SUPERVISORS", line 5
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'APPS.SUPERVISORS'


Error starting at line : 37 in command -
insert into employee values ( 5, 1, 6 )
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-20005: Cannot insert/update record into table Employee. Supervisor ID not found.
ORA-06512: at "APPS.SUPERVISORS", line 13
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'APPS.SUPERVISORS'


1 row inserted.


1 row inserted.


1 row inserted.


1 row inserted.


Error starting at line : 42 in command -
insert into employee values ( 0, 0, 4 )
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-20004: Cannot insert/update record into table Employee. Employee rank is not valid for given supervisor.
ORA-06512: at "APPS.SUPERVISORS", line 17
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'APPS.SUPERVISORS'

Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options
```